# What is this fungus that looks like a brain coral?

Tags: identification, fungus

It looks like a brain coral. It is about a foot in diameter. It is Dry to the touch but still a bit soft. I live in [Prince Edward Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Edward_Island) in Canada.

[image: Fungus or not?]

Comment: Did you check: If you push it gently, does it release spores (cloud of dust) and is it really rooted to the spot where you found it? Or is the brainy-thingy firm and only the moss soft? Do you have *more* pictures? Welcome to the site, btw!

Comment: The grey part is soft? Crumbly soft? Would you be willing to pick it up and turn it over?

Answer (score 5):

I've got to say that  looks an awful lot like a brain coral with moss growing on it. I know of no mushrooms that look nearly as similar to brain coral, and I don't think any fungal fruiting body would last long enough on the ground to grow moss like that.

I think someone went to Florida or the Bahamas many years ago, and brought back a souvenir. We've got some sitting in our woods from family trips we took 30 years ago.

You could rule that out fairly quickly, though, by poking it. Is it solid or yielding? If it gives a bit when poked, you can rule out the coral.

Comment: Now I am concerned that this answer comes across as snarky. That was not my intent.

Comment: I see your thoughts went in the same direction as mine - hence my request for a "poking and lifting test". +1!

Answer (score -3):

Calvatia craniiformis (Brain puffball)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it. Don't post near-identical answers.

Comment: You should explain how it could be this, and why it is not.